# How do I move a local only git repo that has no remote under a remote repo that I do not own while preserving the git history?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a local git repo `my_local_repo` with some commits, but no associated remote.

I want to now move this repo under a folder `foo` under a remote repo called `sandbox` that is administered by someone else but I have been invited to.
I want the git history of my local repo to be preserved in the remote.

So, after the merge, I want to have the remote repo look like:

- sandbox

  - foo

    - my_local_repo

In the future, my_local_repo may be moved as its own repo to production code, so good to preserve its own git history.

How can I do this? There are many many questions and answers very related to this, but cannot find this exact scenario addressed.

Comment: You can do it with `git filter-branch` ... good luck! Maybe `git subtree` can help?.

Comment: What will `my_local_repo` become ? Do you still want to have access to it as a completely separate repo (that would be the submodule way) ? or do you want it to only be part of the `sanbox` repo ?

Comment: @LeGEC (Edited): actually better as a submodule, since I may want to move that my_local_repo to a production repo in the future.

Answer (score 0):

git submodule seems to fit your requirement. I think you plan to host your local repo on a server as well.

1. Clone sandbox
2. Move to foo
3. git submodule add https://repserver.com/my_repo

However, there is a specific workflow you need to follow for git submodules.
Please refer the documentation at below link.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules on how to configure and use.

Comment: sandbox is the remote, foo goes under sandbox, and my repo is local only. Can you update the steps? They seem to address it in reverse. I can clone sandbox, add a folder foo under it. Now, how do I add my local only repo my_repo under foo such that my_repo history is retained?

Comment: @Anand : making your local repo available should be the easy part : choose a hosting service (for example : the same one as the `sandbox` project), create an empty project and push your repo to that new remote.

Comment: @LeGEC I want this local repo to go under a remote that is managed by another person.

Comment: @Anand, assuming sandbox is on github, you can host your local_repo on github on it's own and then follow the above steps.

Comment: @Anand : ok : ask that person where you should push your local repo

Comment: @LeGEC - that is not a preferable option here.

Comment: @Anand : where can you publish your local repo ?

Comment: @LeGEC - only under that provided remote ( kind of a policy/security thing)

Comment: @Anand : it looks like you didn't describe the complete constraints you have to work with. Can you update your question with the information about how that would be submodules should be hosted ?

Comment: @LeGEC - I have updated my question with further details - let me know if that clarifies?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, submodules are fetched from another remote.

I didn't understand the reasons why, but it looks like you want to publish your project as a submodule to a third party shared repo, without creating a new remote repository (not on your side, not on the third party side).
Please correct me if I misunderstood.

---

There could be one way around that : push your local project, under a dedicated set of references on the existing shared repo :

```
# either as regular branches, prefixed with a chosen name :
git push upstream master:refs/heads/subproject/master

# or under refs which wouldn't be listed as regular branches or tags :
git push upstream master:refs/subproject/master
```

If the third party is ok with that, you can then include your project as a submodule, which would fetch its data from the same remote.

Comment: To  explain why, not the actual situation but  analogous. Consider that I do work for a client, and the code is their property. They don't want me to save their code in my git repo. They want it saved in their  remote. They want me to check in code into their  remote under a sandbox till all acceptance criteria are met, then  move it as a top level repo in their remote. They also have strict criteria for top level repos in their business so I would not create a top level repo on their remote until it hmet their requirements.

Comment: "in their remote under a sandbox" : that part needs to be clarified : either there is something to push to or there isn't. Check with that third party what they mean by "sandbox" : is it a branch with a given convention in an existing repo ? a complete separate repo somewhere which won't be flagged as "top level" ? something else ... ?